# r merge multiple data tables with list generated dynamically

Tags: r, merge, data.table

This code works fine but requires knowledge of the data table names ahead of time to construct `list(x,y,z)`

```
library(data.table)
x <- data.table(i = c("a","b","c"), j = 1:3)
y <- data.table(i = c("b","c","d"), k = 4:6)
z <- data.table(i = c("c","d","a"), l = 7:9)

Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE, by = "i"), list(x, y, z))
```

But I have a script that generates the data tables (the names are constructed dynamically) and creates a character vector as follows:

```
dtList <- c("x", "y", "z")
```

I want to use dtList in the Reduce code. I have tried a variety of things. None of these work

```
list(dtList)
as.vector(dtList, mode = "list")
```

Comment: Always with similar questions the problem comes from bad design upstream. If you generate your tables automatically, you can/should store them into a list. There is no good reason to solve your question in my opinion. Showing us how you generate the tables may be more profitable.

Comment: How can I store x, y, and z from the example above as a list?

Comment: `list(x,y,z)` but you  already know it. The question is why you don't know the names of the variables without `dtList`? This is necessarily the result of a bad design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code I came up with following JRR's comments that seems to work for my particular setup. dtNameList is actually read in from somewhere else in my full code but for this example, I just created a dummy version of it.

```
library(data.table)
dtList <- list()

dtNameList <- c("x", "y", "z")
for (k in 1:length(dtNameList)){
  dt <- data.table(i = c("a","b","c"), j = 1:3)
#  assign(k, dt)
  dtList[[dtNameList[k]]] <- dt
}
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE, by = "i"), dtList)
```

Comment: Code can be reduced with mget: `dtList <- mget(dtNameList)`

Comment: Or eapply: `dtList <- eapply(globalenv(), function(i) i)[dtNameList]`

Comment: Wow! The `mget` solution works and replaces several lines of code!

Comment: Or `lapply: dtList <- lapply(dtNameList, get)`. Look into `lapply` or `eapply` in case you need to do operations on each dataframe prior to saving to list where their *function* argument can be expanded as `mget` does not allow this.

Comment: JRR, can you explain why the mget solution is bad code and what you would do instead?